# Virtualbox No suitable module for running kernel found

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I use  remote machine ubuntu 12.04 (console only)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

i have some strange kernel 
uname -a
Linux  2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 15 17:44:15 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

-maybe beeter is switch to other kernel ? how to do it ?

(i try install virtual machine on this server)

apt-get install virtualbox

```
Konfigurowanie virtualbox (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.5) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                             Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
                                                                                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                             Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                                           [fail]


Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...                                                                       
First Installation: checking all kernels...                                                                        
dpkg: ostrzeżenie: wersja "*-*" ma złą składnię: version number does not start with digit                          
It is likely that 2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 belongs to a chroot's host                                       
Building initial module for 2.6.38-10-generic                                                                       
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-10-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-10-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-10-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-10-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 2.6.38-11-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 2.6.38-14-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-14-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-14-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-14-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-14-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 2.6.38-8-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 3.2.0-60-generic

Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.2.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                             Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
                                                                                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                             Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                                           [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Konfigurowanie virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.5) ...
```

i found some info to i must install kerel headers but

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności       
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
E: Nie udało się odnaleźć pakietu linux-headers-2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

(not found)

i found info to install kernel headers but :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64'
```

what can i do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have same error after upgrading `linux-image` package. In order to build modules you need `virtualbox-source` or `virtualbox-dkms` package. I end with `virtualbox-dkms` package.

So I install missing `linux-headers-amd64`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
```

And rebuild `virtualbox.ko`:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority low virtualbox-dkms
```

And load modules:

```
$ sudo service virtualbox start
```

Finally VirtualBox be able to run guests!

Answer (score 10):

Besides `apt-get install virtualbox` you must also run (as root)
`apt-get install virtualbox-source module-assistant
m-a prepare
m-a a-i virtualbox-source`

Then `/etc/init.d/virtualbox start` should work.

Cobbled together from various Google searches, and worked for me on Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, although I installed the virtualbox package after using module-assistant, not before. Also, if you're using a desktop environment, e.g. Cinnamon on Linux Mint, you have to also run `apt-get install virtualbox-qt` in order for the VirtualBox GUI to be available (not really applicable to this question, but hopefully helpful to others who find this).

Comment: Great ! spent hours trying to figure this out, glad I finally found your answer !

Answer (score 2):

*None of the above worked for me. Nor any of what I found on the net actually...*

## TL;DR

If any of you have the same issue, this is the way I fixed it :

```
# cleanup old stuff    
apt-get autoremove --purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt

# install 
echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install virtualbox
```

## Notes

When the install was over **I had a valid virtualbox setup** even though I got an error message during the process => `[FAIL] Starting VirtualBox kernel modules[....] No suitable module for running kernel found ... failed!`

So don't worry as soon as you later have the line `DKMS: install completed.` and you are able to run `vboxmanage --version`

## Specs

My linux server was made of

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:        7
Codename:       wheezy
Kernel:         3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

Comment: *None of the above worked for me.* Actually my answer cover your writing ignoring inessential details. You just can't bake )) Adding `wheezy-backports` is vague step unless you want to work with latest package version.

Comment: @gavenkoa You didn't purge, you didn't use wheezy-backport, and you didn't reinstall the whole package. You do reconfigure and reload the module. So nope : that's not the same ! Your way is accurate, Mine is more global. Maybe everything you described is covered with what I have done, but not the otherway around. Anyway I just wanted to share what I've actually done to get it working as yours did'nt work **for me**. I don't see your point claiming that's the same as it's obviously not, and more over for something you can't even test.

Comment: Think critically! Will you suggest to reinstall OS or switch distro for fix issue? No. Root of problem is **missing kernel modules** or **vbox kernel modules built for old kernel**. So there is 2 solution - **to install missing modules** or **relink modules to newer kernel API**. I think you miss last point in your answer. In any case I usually also use **reinstall all** approach because life is short to understand all in world.